# How do I stretch a specific part of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, python, texturing, scripting, extrude

I have a human head mesh with texture in obj format. But the neck of the head mesh is too short, so I need to stretch the neck section to get a elongated neck.

Also, I want to script the process in Python because it needs to be done many times with head meshes with the same topology.

What I tried to do:

1. Noted down the vertices of the neck boundary clockwise with the **measuring tool** in Blender.
2. I can also get the neck boundary edges similar.

Here is the reference mesh:

[image]

Now I don't know how to stretch those edges down so I get an elongated neck.

---

I have reached a starting point, but the result is not what I would expect:

[image]

The script used:

```
import bpy

def import_obj(filepath):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=filepath,split_mode="OFF")
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

neck_edges=[8413,590,410,4648,13652,1542,15980,15854,14112,14088,228,5131,2233,73,254,8206,11904,11899,13113,10299,7307,7316,14057,14061]

head_path='./temp/head.obj'
out_path='./temp/stretched_head.obj'


import_obj(head_path)
mesh=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
#mesh.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
for edge in mesh.data.edges:
    print(edge.index)
    if edge.index in neck_edges:
        edge.select=True
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_edges_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0.5)})
  
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
mesh.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=out_path,use_selection=True)
```

Any tips on where I'm going wrong? How do I stretch only the neck down?

Comment: This seems ridiculously simple, but the two mentioned attempts don’t sound like you understand what you’re doing. Have you read the Blender Manual or watched any courses?

Comment: @TheLabCat, I'm beginner in this field. I have to script the process in python.

Comment: Why are you scripting it?

Comment: Because, I have to attach it to a lower human body automatically in python script. It's looking weird with short neck.

Comment: You didn’t really answer the question. Why do you need to automate this? It would be several times easier to do it manually.

Comment: Actually, I'm building an application so the end user can see the final result with complete body with face. So no manual things will work in this case.